# Applying rotation transform to a set of four coordinates of a rectangle in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I want to rotate a rectangle for which I have the coordinates of the four vertices. I am doing this by creating a rotation matrix  from the rotation angle and use that to transform the original rectangle coordinates. However, I don't have just one rotation matrix and one rectangle, but many.

My rotation tensor R looks like [n,2,2] (n [2,2] rotation matrices) and my rectangles tensors B looks like [n,4,2] (n [4,2] rectangles). If n was just 1, I could just do normal tf.matmul(R,B), but here I don't know how to do this. I think I can do it with tf.einsum but I don't know how to form the equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried using `quads = tf.einsum('hik,hkj->hij', rot_mat, quads)` but it gives me the following error.
```ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 32 elements to shape [4,2,2] (16 elements) for 'einsum/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [4,4,2], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [4,2,2].```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tf.matmul for batch multiplication. But you have to reshape:

```
a = tf.random.uniform([10, 2, 2])
b = tf.random.uniform([10, 4, 2])
a = a[:, tf.newaxis, ...]
b = b[..., tf.newaxis]
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
c = tf.squeeze(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `quads = tf.einsum('hik,hkj->hij', rot_mat, quads)` worked for me when I arranged the rectangle coordinates as [n, 2, 4].